# How to parse a shape file to use in Foundry's map application?

Tags: pyspark, geospatial, shapefile, palantir-foundry

I am ingesting data in the form of a shapefile.  For example, ice data from https://usicecenter.gov/Products

How do I use these files in Foundry, in particular displaying on a map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy!  This is outlined in the documentation on using [vector data in transforms](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/geospatial/vector_data_in_transforms/)

Clean geospatial data in Foundry is:

1. Tabular, so the data can be used in Spark transforms
2. Formatted as either a valid GeoJSON or geohash, so [Geospatial data can be used in the Foundry Ontology](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/geospatial/ontology/)
3. Projected using the `EPSG:4326 CRS`, so that both sides of spatial joins use the same projection and Foundry maps will render features correctly.

Foundry provides a `geospatial-tools` pyspark library which makes it easy to clean and convert.  Further details are in the documentation for [data parsing and cleaning](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/geospatial/vector_data_in_transforms/), but for this specific example, we would need to convert the shapefile into a dataframe and then project to `EPSG:4326`.

The EPSG can be determined from the `.prj` file, using the method outlined [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/shapefile-prj-to-postgis-srid-lookup-table/7615#7615).  For the example of the ice shapefiles:

```
with open(shapeprj_path, 'r') as f:
        prj_txt = f.read()
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.ImportFromESRI([prj_txt])
    print(str(srs.ExportToProj4()))
```

The output is:
`+proj=lcc +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-100 +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`

This is used as the `input_crs`:

```
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output
from geospatial_tools import geospatial
from geospatial_tools.parsers import shapefile_to_dataframe
from geospatial_tools.geom_transformations import normalize_projection


@geospatial()
@transform(
    output=Output("path/to/ice_data_parsed"),
    raw=Input("path/to/ice_data_raw"),
)
def compute(raw, output):
    gdf = shapefile_to_dataframe(raw)
    gdf = normalize_projection(input_df=gdf, geometry_column="geometry", input_crs="+proj=lcc +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-100 +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
output.write_dataframe(gdf)
```

The output dataset can then be [synced to the Ontology](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/geospatial/ontology/#how-to-configure-ontology-datasets-with-vector-data) and [used in the mapping applications](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/geospatial/ontology/#how-to-visualize-explore-and-publish-geospatial-data)